# How to access class variable in Model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I want to define the class variable `test`, `threshold`

so that I can use  `Order.test, Order.threshold` in my Rails app

but I can not access the class variable when using the rails console

I must misunderstand something, where's the problem? Thanks.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@test=123
  @@threshold = {
    VIP: 500,
    PLATINUM: 20000
  }
```

Here is the `rails console`

```
irb(main):001:0> Order.class_variables
=> [:@@test, :@@threshold]
irb(main):002:0> Order.test
NoMethodError: private method `test' called for #<Class:0x007fe5a63ac738>
```

Comment: why dont you use constants?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   cattr_reader :test, :threshold
   self.test = 123
   self.threshold = {
     VIP: 500,
     PLATINUM: 20000
   }
end  

Order.test
```

Or I'd use constants:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   TEST = 123
end

Order::TEST
```

Comment: Rails 4+ use similar method mattr_accessor

Answer (score 5):

I would just use class methods:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.test
    123
  end

  def self.threshold
    { VIP: 500, PLATINUM: 20000 }
  end
end
```

Constants would work, as well, but if you already have code that expects `Order.test` and `Order.threshold` to exist, you'd have to change your code to call the constant instead. Plus, Avdi Grimm gives some good reasons for using methods instead of constants [in a blog post](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/08/18/do-we-need-constants/).

The reason accessing class variables won't work the way you expected is that Ruby restricts access to variables like this. You need to either define accessor methods directly (like `self.test` or `self.threshold`), or indirectly using something like [`cattr_reader`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Class/cattr_reader). You could also use [`cattr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor) if you need to write to the variables from the outside world.

I would generally recommend avoiding class variables, though. They have some [unintuitive behavior](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).